# ionic capacitor ios app shows white screen only on simulator but runs for real device

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

i recently moved to a new macbook with m1 chip, the ionic capacitor app which was running perfectly fine n intel based mac is now showing white screen after splash screen. if i try to run it connecting my device app runs perfectly. problem is only with the simulator
xcode version 13.1
mac os bigSur
Projrct Angular ionic capacitor based

Comment: Need more details about your project. What plugins are you using? and other details. Also share your package.json file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.